# How to declare a global class so I don't get an error in Undefined type in intelephense in visual code

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, wp-cli, intelephense

I'm new to visual studio code and intelephense.
I'm working with WordPress and using a class called WP_CLI which's a system installed. So, if I'm not wrong, class WP_CLI is not in my path so I get `Undefined type 'WP_CLI'.intelephense(1009)`

The ideal solution for me would be to be able to tell inteliphense that WP_CLI is defined elsewhere and not to bother with this error. Not to disable Undefined type altogether.

I can't find the comment to disable it.
I've found the similar `/** @var int $foo */` for variables but I can't find the documentation for it so I can do the same with classes.

Is there an option to do that?

Comment: Yeah really annoying, the only solution I found so far was to disable all "undefined type" errors but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

It's not super clear on how to install the stubs.  in your project folder run

`composer require --dev php-stubs/wp-cli-stubs`

in that same folder, you will need a workspace file.  they have the `.code-workspace` extension.  in there you need

```
{
    "settings": {
        "intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
            "path/to/vendor"
        ]
    }
}
```

you also need WordPress in `settings.intelephense.stubs`

hope this saves someone some time and let me know if there is a better way

Answer (score 2):

I found installing the [stubs for WP_CLI](https://github.com/php-stubs/wp-cli-stubs) fixes the issue.